# Odata query expand grandchild in Dynamics

Tags: dynamics-crm, odata, microsoft-dynamics, powerapps

I have the following simple data structure:

Advance

- Advancing groups - Advancing Recipients
- Job
- Location

I need to retrieve all advances and their Job, Location and Advancing Recipients details.

I can expand to the job, Location and Advancing group but I can't get back any details about the Recipients. Is there an odata flag that I need to use too expand to Grandchild?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What have you tried? Why isn't it working?

What have you searched?

Where are you using the query?

The following is straight from the docs:

```
GET [Organization URI]/api/data/v9.1/tasks?$select=subject
&$expand=regardingobjectid_contact_task($select=fullname;
 $expand=parentcustomerid_account($select=name;
  $expand=createdby($select=fullname))) HTTP/1.1  
Accept: application/json  
OData-MaxVersion: 4.0  
OData-Version: 4.0
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/webapi/retrieve-related-entities-query

Comment: Thanks Chris! I  I'm getting  "The navigation property 'new_new_advgrp_new_advrrc' can't be expanded. Only many-to-one relationships are supported for nested expansion."